# rails quiz implementation: saving points per answer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I am making a quiz-like app that has multiple *questions* that have multiple *answers*. Each answer has a *points* and the *id_of_next_question* attributes - depending on the answer the user should be presented with a different question.

The easy way to do this would be to do sth like this:

< @question.answers.each do |answer| %>

<= link_to answer.content, question_path(answer.id_of_next_question) %>

< end %>

But this has the down side that the user would see the ids of the Questions in the path and I don't know how I would collect the answer.points with link_to.

What would be a proper way to make a i.e. .../play.html view that shows the 1st question, and depending on the answer, calculates points=points+answer.points and renders the next question with answers without changing the ".../play.html" path?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be to have your links act like a form which creates a new question_result (a model where you save the user's choice),

for example

> < @question.answers.each do |answer| %>
>    <= link_to answer.content, question_results_path(:question_id => @question.id , :answer_id => answer.id) , :method => :post %>
>   < end %>

then in a question_results_controller, you can have a create action, which calculates the points using the answer_id, and redirects the user back to the play.html path, with as a parameter the next question id so that the user can continue the quiz. You could save the points total as a cookie (although a more proper way to do it would be to have a user model, and save the results per user in the db)